# Bobblehead - Avoda Zara issue?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah

Would there be any issue (like Avoda Zara perhaps) with gifting someone a bobblehead of a family member?

Comment: There are halachic debates about dolls in general

Comment: https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol3Issue8.pdf

Comment: https://outorah.org/p/6084/

Comment: @Chatzkel to add to that, a bobblehead may be prohibited even according to some of those who permit dolls. One common reason given to permit dolls is that it is something treated bderekh bizayon, as it is tossed around, on the floor, etc. The same may not be true of bobbleheads which are usually better taken care of.

Comment: Another point to consider is that the doll is not made to scale of a human body

Comment: @Chatzkel re: your last point about it not being to scale - is that a reason in favor of permitting it or prohibiting it?

Comment: @michael I believe there are those who permit it based on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an article on [DinOnline](https://dinonline.org/2015/09/04/bobblehead-dolls/) that discusses this exact issue.

He says it's mutar because they're never used for Avoda Zara. The full answer and sources can be found [here](https://dinonline.org/2015/09/04/bobblehead-dolls/).